# Как сложить все переменные массива

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Нашел функцию для сложения всех элементов, reduce(), но почему-то при использовании ее, у меня вместо того, чтобы сложились все переменные в массиве, выводит

```
0[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]
```

```js
const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data() {
      return {
         Count: [{banana: 128}, {apple: 128}, {pich: 128}, {watermallon: 128}, {plum: 128}],
      }
   },
   methods: {
      totalCount () {
         return this.Count.reduce((acc, n) => {
            return acc += n
         }, 0)
       }
   },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="price">
    {{totalCount()}}
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Потому что функция предназначена для нумерованного массива, а у тебя массив объектов, причем с разными ключами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном конкретном случае можно сделать так

```
this.Count..reduce((acc, n) => {
    return acc += Object.values(n)[0]
}, 0)
```

Но это решает проблему исключительно массива объектов, в котором будет один ключ с одним значением.